# mysql select MAX but display not as expected

Tags: mysql, max

i have a query looking for max value, but display not as expected

this is my data in table 
[image]

i just to get max value in this column. 
i use query
"`SELECT max(substr(no_box,3)) as maxnb FROM`tbl_pengecekan" but display value is 9

[image]

**the expected value is 10**

please help me

Comment: What's the max value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to cast substr(no_box,3) to int then apply max

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4de24a663ecea8d4e44dce9800a60ae8)

```
select max(cast(substr(no_box,3) as signed)) from tablename
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do take the max value by removing the `A-` from the string.

**Query**

```
select max(`t`.`num`) as `maxnb` from (
    select cast(replace(`no_box`, 'A-', '') as signed) as `num`
   from `tbl_pengecekan`
) as `t`;
```

An other way around is, order the column first by descending order of the length and then descending order of the column itself. And then limit the result to 1.

**Query**

```
select replace(`no_box`, 'A-', '') as `maxnb`
from `tbl_pengecekan`
order by length(`no_box`) desc, `no_box` desc limit 1;
```

**[Find a demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8c21118/1)**

Comment: I believe the syntax is for another SQL-server than what the author is using. The author is using MySQL and this seems to be the Microsofty version of SQL :) But the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the value `9` because that's the *lexigraphical* maximum value in the set your querying on. If you want to get the *numerical* maximum value you must first [cast](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) the values to integers (basically convert from `string` to `int`). You can do this with `cast(substr(no_box, 3) as signed)`

**Full code**

```
SELECT 
    max(cast(substr(no_box, 3) as signed)) as maxnb 
FROM tbl_pengecekan
```